# Quickest way to find if there is a common element between 2 vectors in CPP

Tags: c++

I want to check *if* there are common elements between 2 vectors. Is there a quicker way than looping through each element for both vectors and checking if they are the same?

By *common element* I mean an element "a" that exists in both vectors.

I only want to check IF there are common elements not how many, so I was thinking maybe I could use that to make a quicker piece of code.

I was also thinking of adding all elements to a set and checking if the set's size is equal to the sum of the sizes of the two vectors. Would this work?

The two vectors consist of vectors of chars. For example

```cpp
vector<vector<char>> vec1 = {{'a','b'}, {'c'}};
vector<vector<char>> vec2 = {{'a'},{'b'},{'c'}};
// Notice that, in this case, {'c'} would the the common element
// because it exists in both vectors
```

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly certain there's a quicker way, as you're asking. Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Comment: [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)? Seems like a good place to start. Let the efficiency of the algorithm help you look at both vectors for a common element.

Comment: When you say common elements, do you mean any common elements (e.g., if vector {'x', 'h', 'a', r'}  has an 'a'), common runs of elements (i.e., a substring), or something different? If the former, would it be feasible to use a `std::vector<std::set<char> >` instead of a  `std::vector<std::vector<char> >`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant common elements as in elements that appear in both vectors. I included an example in the question.

Also, would adding all the elements to a set and then checking if the size is the same as the sum of the sizes of the vectors be a quicker and valid method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

We can create a `set` to store the elements in one vector.

```cpp
set<vector<char>> elements;
for (auto v : vec1) {
    elements.insert(v);
}
```

Then iterating through the elements in the second vector, to see if they exist in the unordered_set:

```cpp
for (auto v : vec2) {
    if (elements.count(v) > 0) {
        // do the logic for common elements
    }
}
```

Comment: "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to clog up the drain" -- Scotty, Star Trek III. An unordered set has to deal with heap allocation, hashing, and other wonderfully sophisticated algorithms. A single `char [256]` array, which is perfectly sufficient, requires none of that jazz, and results in the same number of physical lines, each one of which which will likely compile down to a single machine-language instruction. I would not give even a modern C++ compiler's good chances of optimizing an unordered-set based logic, equivalently.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I agree with you. For simple chars, using set or unordered_set is an overkill. A boolean array is sufficient for 256 characters. However, sometimes we might have other types like strings, or as mentioned in the question, vector of chars. In these situations, a single array is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to duplicate the two inputs into `set`s, one simple way to do the job would be to use `std::set_intersection` and check whether the result is empty:

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using container = std::vector<std::vector<char>>;

// sets are sorted, so we need to support comparison for the contained object
bool operator<(std::vector<char> const &a, std::vector<char> const &b) {
    std::string aa(a.begin(), a.end());
    std::string bb(b.begin(), b.end());

    return aa < bb;
}

bool contains_common_element(container const &a, container const &b) {
    container intersection;

    std::set<std::vector<char>> aa { a.begin(), a.end() };
    std::set<std::vector<char>> bb { b.begin(), b.end() };

    std::set_intersection(aa.begin(), aa.end(),
                          bb.begin(), bb.end(),
                          std::inserter(intersection, intersection.end()));

    return !intersection.empty();
}

int main() {
    using std::vector;

    // do a few tests:
    vector<vector<char>> vec1 = {{'a','b'}, {'c'}};
    vector<vector<char>> vec2 = {{'a'},{'b'},{'c'}};
    vector<vector<char>> vec3 = {{ 'd'}, {'a', 'b'}};
    vector<vector<char>> vec4 = {{ 'e' } , {'f'}};

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << contains_common_element(vec1, vec2) << "\n";
    std::cout << contains_common_element(vec1, vec3) << "\n";
    std::cout << contains_common_element(vec2, vec3) << "\n";
    std::cout << contains_common_element(vec3, vec4) << "\n";
}
```

This could be somewhat inefficient though: it'll scan through the entirety of both inputs looking for all intersections, where we only care whether there's at least one.